# Org-mode overline emphasis not able to be followed by other characters

Tags: org-mode

I use a lot of overline (in statistical formulae) and so I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(org-emphasis-alist
     (quote (("*" bold)
             ("/" italic)
             ("_" underline)
             ("=" org-verbatim verbatim)
             ("+" (:strike-through t))
             ("~" (:overline t) verbatim))))
     '(org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
     '(org-pretty-entities t))
```

In other words, I want `~` to define overline and I want it to render in-line in Emacs.

This works great, however I cannot follow that emphasis (or any emphasis for that matter) with more characters such as superscript or subscript numbers. For example, `~X~_1` renders as literally `~X~` followed by a subscript `1`. The `X` is overlined *until* I type the underscore, then the emphasis tildes reappear.

I assume the solution has something to do with modifying `org-emphasis-regexp-components` and maybe use of a zero-width space between the emphasis and the subscript, but there I get lost.

Also I would love my PDF exports to render the same (at the moment, since I am using the `~` for overline, my overlined segments get rendered as code) so for a part 2, if we can update the PDF export to render overlines properly too, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about having to modify `org-emphasis-regexp-components`. In particular, you have to add `_` and `^` to the regexp for the `post` component (be careful where you add them: leave the dash at the very beginning and leave the opening square bracket at the very end - I added them after the initial dash below):

```el
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
    (setf (nth 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "-_^[:space:].,:!?;'\")}\\[")

    (setf (nth 4 org-emphasis-alist) '("~" (:overline t) verbatim))

  #+end_src
```

After setting the latter, you need to reload Org mode as its doc string states: `M-x org-reload RET`.

That should take care of subscripts and superscripts in the buffer.

For PDF rendering, a possible implementation is to replace the current rendering of the `code` markup with an overline rendering. The relevant data structure is `org-latex-text-markup-alist`: we replace the code element with one of our own devising:

```el
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
    (require 'ox-latex)

    (delete (assoc 'code org-latex-text-markup-alist) org-latex-text-markup-alist)
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-text-markup-alist '(code . "\\ensuremath{\\overline{%s}}"))
  #+end_src
```

That uses the `\overline` macro (which is only defined in math environments, hence the `\ensuremath`). That seems to work in the simple cases in your question. No guarantees however: there may be more complicated cases that break this.

The `require` might be needed in order to pick up the definition of the variable `org-latex-text-markup-list`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first section works brilliantly. The latex markup section errors out though: "delete: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-latex-text-markup-alist". Emacs 26.3 (Cygwin build).

Comment: Ah, you may be running an older version of Org mode that does not have that variable. What version *are* you running? `M-x org-version RET` will tell, `C-u M-x org-version RET` will insert it in a buffer so you can cut-and-paste and you should update your question with that information ... or you might need to `(require 'ox-latex)` to get the definition of the variable.

Comment: The `require` will probably resolve it: the variable was introduced way back before 8.3.7.

Comment: The require did it! Looks fantastic and the use-cases I need it for all seem to render properly in emacs and PDF export. Thanks so much! Will tag it as answered. As an aside, any idea how I can, both in emacs and PDF export, render a d with a ^ above it? This is an estimate of Cohen's d (i.e. d-hat) in statistics-land. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask a new question: tacking on another question in a comment is generally discouraged.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!