# org mode export to latex a backslash followed by ordinary text

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

The following `org-mode` MCE points out a problem when one wants to export a backslash immediately followed by ordinary text (e.g. `~\~foo` is exported to `\textasciitilde{}$\backslash$~foo` where one expects `\texttt{\textbackslash{}}foo`). As a poor man workaround, one can insert a line break between `~\~` and `foo` but this inserts a line break in the exported `.tex` file and hence a space in the resulting PDF.

How to workaround this issue?

```
~\~

~\foo~

~\~foo

~\~
foo

=\=

=\foo=

=\=foo

=\=
foo
```

Comment: Can you insert a non breaking space instead? \nbsp?

Comment: If the non-breaking space workaround is not enough, do `C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components`. There have been questions on that here (e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60533/org-mode-overline-emphasis-not-able-to-be-followed-by-other-characters).

Comment: @JohnKitchin I would like to avoid spaces: I would like `~\~foo` to result in fine in `\`foo (sigh, I can't get it to work with Markdown. In LaTeX, I want it to be `\texttt{\textbackslash{}}foo`, hence no space between the backslash and "foo".

Comment: @NickD Sigh... Why life (I mean `org-mode`) is so complicated? Compared to `org-mode`, LaTeX looks extremely simple :$

Comment: Well, 99.5% of simple things are simpler in Org than in LaTeX, but this certainly belongs to the other portion: simple things that are more complicated in Org. If you only want Latex output, then I would suggest  using literal LaTeX in your org file with `@@latex:\textt{\textbackslash}@@` as a simpler alternative, but that won't work for HTML export e.g. The desire to make things work across export backends is what complicates Org mode in this case.

Comment: You could also try a zero width space https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html and https://thewanderingcoder.com/2015/03/emacs-org-mode-styling-non-smart-quotes-zero-width-space-and-tex-input-method/

Comment: @JohnKitchin That did the trick! If you convert your comment in a (maybe a bit more self-explanatory) answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a zero width space for this (https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html). This will allow the code markup to work, but will not be visible in the export, or in the org file. That char acts like a space, but it has zero width.  If you need this a lot there is a convenient function and key binding to insert a zero width space at https://thewanderingcoder.com/2015/03/emacs-org-mode-styling-non-smart-quotes-zero-width-space-and-tex-input-method/.