# Org-mode formatting a term with a suffix but without any preceeding space

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I export an Org-mode document with `~if~s`, I expect it to show

`if`s

However, I get `~if~s` or sometimes `ifs ...` if there's a following `=` somewhere down the line.  I also tried using a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) in vain.  How can I get the above?

I don't think the root cause is just at exporting, I see the same issue in the org buffer too.

Comment: This is controlled by the (rather complicated) variable `org-emphasis-regexp-components` (see its doc string with `C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components`) which you can customize. See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60533/org-mode-overline-emphasis-not-able-to-be-followed-by-other-characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Org-mode overline emphasis not able to be followed by other characters](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60533/org-mode-overline-emphasis-not-able-to-be-followed-by-other-characters)